# Maven PDF doesn't include site information

Tags: maven, pdf

Using:

- Maven 3.2.3
- Java 1.8

I generated the site by using:

```
mvn site
```

I then wanted to generate the PDF from this generated site (which according to the [PDF Plugin Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/usage.html), it uses the site documents). I just ran the command:

```
mvn pdf:pdf
```

Maven does generate a PDF, but all it does is show the Project Name, version, "Project Documentation" and a TOC that doesn't go anywhere. All the site information is missing.

Do I need to include something in the POM or something else to get this to work? I appreciate the help!

**UPDATE**

As per a comment below, I have tried using a `pdf.xml`, which seems to be getting me closer to the output I am looking for.

The **pdf.xml** looks like:

```
<document xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DOCUMENT/1.0.1
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/document-1.0.1.xsd"
          outputName="MyProject">

    <meta>
        <title>My Project</title>
        <author>IT Department</author>
    </meta>

    <toc name="Table of Contents">
        <item name="Introduction" ref="index.html"/>
        <item name="Goals" ref="project-info.html"/>
        <item name="Dependencies" ref="dependencies.html"/>
        <item name="Dependency Tree" ref="dependency-tree.html"/>
        <item name="Team" ref="team-list.html"/>
    </toc>

    <cover>
        <coverTitle>${project.name}</coverTitle>
        <coverSubTitle>v. ${project.version}</coverSubTitle>
        <coverType>User Guide</coverType>
        <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
        <projectLogo>http://somesite.com/logo.jpg</projectLogo>
        <companyName>Google</companyName>
        <companyLogo>http://google.com/logo.gif</companyLogo>
    </cover>
</document>
```

The HTML files I refer to are in `/src/site`. They are then also put into `/target/pdf/site.tmp` folder.

Maven gives the follow output, that has issues:

```
[INFO] --- maven-pdf-plugin:1.3:pdf (pdf) @ myproject---
[WARNING] Bookmarks: Unresolved id reference "./project-info" found.
[WARNING] Bookmarks: Unresolved id reference "./dependencies" found.
[WARNING] Bookmarks: Unresolved id reference "./dependency-tree" found.
[WARNING] Bookmarks: Unresolved id reference "./team-list" found.
[WARNING] Bookmarks: Unresolved id reference "./index" found.
[WARNING] Page i: Unresolved id reference "./project-info" found.
[WARNING] Page i: Unresolved id reference "./dependencies" found.
[WARNING] Page i: Unresolved id reference "./dependency-tree" found.
[WARNING] Page i: Unresolved id reference "./team-list" found.
[WARNING] Page i: Unresolved id reference "./index" found.
[WARNING] Bookmark with IDRef "./index" has a null PageViewport.
[WARNING] Bookmark with IDRef "./project-info" has a null PageViewport.
[WARNING] Bookmark with IDRef "./dependencies" has a null PageViewport.
[WARNING] Bookmark with IDRef "./dependency-tree" has a null PageViewport.
[WARNING] Bookmark with IDRef "./team-list" has a null PageViewport.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.354 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-20T10:03:37-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/318M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No matter what I try, I cannot resolve the **Unresolved id reference** issue. the PDF generates and the TOC is shown, but no numbers to the right and no other pages are shown.

Comment: You should generate the site by ´mvn site` and not by calling the `maven-site-plugin`....

Comment: @khmarbaise -  I tried generating the site like that and the PDF still does not generate properly. But I will generate the site that way for now on, thank you!

Comment: The pdf plugin should be bound to the life cycle instead of calling it via goal  `pdf:pdf` better look at the configuration to integrate it into the build life cycle.

Comment: I tried that as well. Using the link in the question, I followed the "As Part Of Your Build Process" but it still just generates the same output

Comment: I tried `mvn pdf:pdf`on my Maven project and it's fine: I have the same content as in my site. Do you have a src/site/site.xml ?

Comment: @olivierlemasle - I do not have that file. It did not generate it... unless that's a manual file I am suppose to create? haha

Comment: @Ascalonian, Ok, I've added an answer related to this file.

Comment: @olivierlemasle - I've replied back to it and added more to the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maven PDF Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/) seems to require a *Document Descriptor* (see the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pdf-plugin/usage.html), paragraph *Document Descriptor*).

By default, it uses the site-plugin's `src/site/site.xml` (see explanations on site-plugin's documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html).
You can choose to use `src/site/pdf.xml` instead; it's a document descriptor targeting specifically the PDF generation.

**Update:**

A good directory structure is:

```
+- src/
   +- site/
      +- apt/
      |  +- index.apt
      |  +- team.apt
      |
      +- xdoc/
      |  +- other.xml
      |
      +- site.xml
      +- pdf.xml
```

In this example, you have three source documents (index.apt, team.apt and other.xml), which can be used in the website (transformed as html files) or in the PDF.

Comment: So when I run `mvn site`, it puts all files into **/target/site** instead. I moved all those files into **/src/site** and created the `site.xml` file. It is creating the menu I want now, but I get a lot of "Unresolved id reference" so the rest of the pages are not generated.

Comment: I tried using `pdf.xml` which seems to give me more of what I want. However, I am getting the same issue. I will update my question with more  this detail

Comment: You don't have to move files from target to src. The PDF plugin will use the source files (ie apt, xdoc... files) from /src/site.

Comment: I had to create /src/site, which is why I moved them over.

Comment: Ok, I expected you had a `src/site` with static content. Do you want the PDF only for reports?

Comment: I wanted the reports to be included as well as the static content

Comment: But where was you static content if not in src/site?

Comment: Was starting with the reports first. So I got the right structure now (thank you!) but now I just need to figure out how to link the reports

Comment: @Ascalonian Did you find the way to link the reports?

Comment: I believe I did, but since this a little over 2 years ago and I am not at the same employer, I do not remember how it was done haha.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I guess the error is due to the fact that markdown is not supported by default by the maven-pdf plugin. I had the same issue I was able to fix it by adding the following plugin configuration in my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pdf</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>pdf</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <includeReports>false</includeReports>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                    <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```